# Jetpack Compose Performance Issue that only occurs in multi module project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have developed a quite complex keyboard layout in Jetpack Compose. Initially, the layout works fine and animations run very smoothly when pressign the keys. Unfortunately, after a few recompositions due to events the animations and everything becomes very slow and laggy.
I have tried to sample Jave Method calls and I can only see that some function take a lot longer than usual.

**Edit:**
I have been able to isolate the issue. I have discovered that the performance issue only appears in multi module projects. When I put the *exact same* compose code in the root `app` module the issue disappears.

I have created a project that reproduces the issue:

- [Mutli Module Project with performance issue](https://github.com/THEAccess/example_compose-keyboard-multimodule)
- [Single Module Project without performace issue](https://github.com/THEAccess/example_compose-keyboard-multimodule)

If you want to reproduce the issue in the multi module project you have to switch between the categories multiple times and then everything becomes very laggy

[image: Example Video]

*Note: I know Jetpack Compose is still in alpha and this issue might be a bug in Jetpack Compose. But I want to make sure that it's not a bug of my code or a general limitation of Compose*

Comment: The library states it "recomposes" intelligently only updating what has changed. I'd check that you don't have some infinite loops running on mutable state. To detect screen "jank" use the normal mechanism explained here - https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/render

Comment: This is a great helper to log the count of recompositions: https://github.com/chrisbanes/tivi/blob/main/common-ui-compose/src/main/java/app/tivi/common/compose/Debug.kt

Comment: if you are not defining the size correctly some items in the xml might take longer than usual. For me I once use the app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="1:1" that is making the app lag because it there was an error and it was calculating the sizes repedeatly. so double check the xml file too

Comment: @Yannick Can you please check my answer? If you have any feedback please let me know. Thanks

Comment: @Abdulrahman Abdelkader The OP is asking about Jetpack Compose, no xml stuff here.

Comment: @Skaldebane ok thanks for letting me know.

Comment: The library cannot recompose intelligently if the Compose Compiler did not evaluate Stability Metrics for your model classes. The Compose Compiler must be executed for the Model classes as well, not just the UI.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to use `remember` composable for `Keyboard` `@Composable` to prevent layouts computation during recomposition.

```
val refs: List<List<Pair<Key, ConstrainedLayoutReference>>> =
         remember {
             keyboard.map { row ->
                row.map {
                   it to createRef()
               }
          }
}

val modifier = remember { ... }

val modifierPressed = remember { ... }
```

**Source code:** https://github.com/dautovicharis/example_compose-keyboard-multimodule/commits/main

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to investigate the issue. Your solution works in the test case scenario I have provided. Unfortunately, It doesn't work in my real app. I have forked your solution and have added functionality that switches the keyboard when (It shows different Key Labels) when one of the items is selected. You can find it here: https://github.com/THEAccess/example_compose-keyboard-singlemodule-w-logic. Also, maybe you can explain why this problem only appears in a multi-module project?

Comment: Only solution I have found is to keep all ConstrainedLayoutReferences by keyboardUniqueID inside HashMap. Code: https://github.com/dautovicharis/example_compose-keyboard-singlemodule-w-logic/commit/02d3b69882153312989b6b5e12de1b2212181964. This is first time I'm playing with Android @Composable - I don't have idea why is this happening only for multi-module project.

Answer (score 2):

In general, there's nothing special about it being a Jetpack Compose app.  You can use the [CPU profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler?hl=en#overview) in Android Studio and [record a trace](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/cpu-profiler?hl=en#method_traces) to see more specifically what's happening within your app.  It's hard to know what is causing some functions to take longer than usual without seeing the code, but it might actually be that they're getting called repeatedly (sampling methods can't tell the difference).

You can also put print statements or breakpoints in your `@Composable` functions.  Make sure that the functions aren't getting called (recomposed) when you're not expecting them to.  If they are, you'll want to investigate what's causing them to get called again.

Comment: I've been able to isolate the cause the performance issue and added a reproducable sample repo

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue (and I have a single-module project) with `LazyColumn` and `LazyVerticalGrid`, which were horribly slow and laggy to the point where I lost faith in Jetpack Compose's promise.

However, it turned out this was all because of Jetpack Compose's internal workings in the `debug` build type, as there's a lot going on under the hood to allow the direct editing of literals and debugging of composables.

The solution was basically to build a release version of the app. This optimizes the code and disables any debugging features, making my app run lag-free, smoothly and rapidly.

Shout out to this [reddit comment](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/oatiur/why_simple_app_with_jetpack_compose_is_5x_times/h3jj1i4?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for suggesting this.

Answer (score 0):

The cause in a multi-module project is that the Compose Compiler ***must*** be executed over your data classes and models in order to calculate their "argument stability metrics".

These are automatically generated by the Compose Compiler. If your module did NOT have the Compose Compiler execute on it (you didn't run Compose on your module) then your "immutable"-seeming data classes will be considered **unstable** by the Compose Compiler, which in turn makes it so that any `@Composable` function that ever gets recomposed and gets one of these "unstable" arguments **will** be re-evaluated (non-skippable, restartable).

Once you add these up, your Composables can re-render the entire UI on every frame. That's when you need to consider `@Stable` deferred read state holders, running the Compose Compiler on your modules including the "non-UI" modules so that you have the proper Compose Stability Metrics, and just make sure you add `remember {}` (so either pass `viewModel::login` or `= remember {{ viewModel.login() }}`) for lambdas you might be passing that have unstable arguments. This can change performance for the positive drastically.